# Change randomly the button names

Tags: c#, button

I have 4 buttons `btn1`  `btn2`  `btn3`  `btn4`

```
q1 = from tAns in db.Questions where tAns.idQuestion == x select tAns;
q2 = from fAns1 in db.Questions where fAns1.idQuestion == x select fAns1;
q3 = from fAns2 in db.Questions where fAns2.idQuestion == x select fAns2;
q4 = from fAns3 in db.Questions where fAns3.idQuestion == x select fAns3;
```

I need a way that it randomly change the text of button... 
Possible outputs:

First time

```
btn1.Text = q2.ToString();
btn2.Text = q4.ToString();
btn3.Text = q3.ToString();
btn4.Text = q1.ToString();
```

Second time

```
btn1.Text = q1.ToString();
btn2.Text = q3.ToString();
btn3.Text = q2.ToString();
btn4.Text = q4.ToString();
```

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're creating a quiz app of some sort, so you need to have only be able to pick a random answer once. Instead of picking a string from an array, just throw all the strings into an array and shuffle the array. A quick and easy way of shuffling the array would be to use the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle).

Then iterate through the buttons in a `for` loop and assign the value to your buttons. (You'll need to add the error checking).

```
for(int i = 0; i < myShuffledArray.Count(); i++)
     myButtonsCollection[i].Text = myShuffledArray[i];
```